# MySQL convert into uppercase does not working

Tags: mysql, hash

I'm using MySQL `PASSWORD()` with manual way since its not working (deprecated) in `MySQL 8`

```
CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('PWD')))))
```

Uppercase `Upper()` conversion is not working with MySQL 5.7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try 'UCASE(...)' ?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT('*', UCASE(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('123456')))))` gives the same results. *6bb4837eb74329105ee4568dda7dc67ed2ca2ad9

Comment: They both work for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e996e89045e3ad6210224aa77cdfc0d4

Comment: I'm getting the results with lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upper function inside another function is not working in some MySQL versions. Its a MySQL bug.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12903

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you are using the proper charset..

> Returns the string str with all characters changed to uppercase
>   according to the current character set mapping. The default is
>   utf8mb4.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper

so check for you charset and eventually change the value you need in select

and just a suggestion if the bugs i related  to the nested  call try using a nested  subquery  eg:

```
select  concat('*', UPPER(t.col))
 from ( select SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('PWD'))) col
) t
```

Comment: `SELECT UPPER('abc')` returns `ABC` but `SELECT CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('123456')))))` returns *6bb4837eb74329105ee4568dda7dc67ed2ca2ad9 in MySQL 5.7

Comment: @user12342428  .. i have add  a suggestion  hope is useful,..